# MacOSX Hooks using DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES (malloc/NSLog)?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

Hello I want to do some hooking for debugging purposes, now I've seen examples that can hook malloc using DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES. But is it also possible to hook NS functions the same way, say for example NSLog?